# How do you apply AngleVector to a list of values?

Tags: list-manipulation

My list is the following:

```
a = {1.1904, 0.475544, 2.44246, 0.576634, 2.40469, 1.28586, 2.73542, 3.07949, 2.25646, 0.44746}
```

`AngleVector[a]` will not give me the appropriate results.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. What you need to do is to [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) your function ``AngleVector`` over your list ``a``. You can do this with ``Map[AngleVector, a]`` or with a shorthand notation ``AngleVector /@ a``.

Comment: Note that `Attributes[AngleVector]` does **not** indicate that `AngleVector` is `Listable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments:

```
a = {1.1904, 0.475544, 2.44246, 0.576634, 2.40469, 1.28586, 2.73542, 
  3.07949, 2.25646, 0.44746}
vecs = AngleVector /@ a
```

To visualize:

```
Graphics[{
  {RandomColor[], Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}]} & /@ vecs
  }
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]